# can not run mysql 8.0 in command line

Tags: mysql

i can not connect to MySql server 8.0 because the path not find
i set the path in enviromnent variables but not work agane
can you help me ?
[image]

Comment: When you use "cd" to change into a directory with spaces you have to use quotes like `cd "C:\Program Files\..."`, otherwise it tries to change into the directory `C:\Program`, which doesn't exists.

Answer (score 1):

As per the the image attached,its failing the **change directory command - cd** , not mysql. try below,

```
cd /d <Path to mysql installation directory>

mysql <command to connect to mysql as need>
```

**Note :** `cd <path>` is the command in linux, in windows we need to use `cd /d <path>`

Hopw it helps